# Tool to remove the password (and encryption) from an Inno Setup installer

Tags: command-line

I have a bunch of Inno Setup installers. They all have password protection enabled and are apparently encrypted. I **have the passwords**.

None of the installers is signed, but they all come from a trustworthy source (as a customer of that company you get your own watermarked version of the software *inside* the installers).

What tool can I use to - *with* knowledge of the password - extract the installer and reassemble it from scratch?

I'm looking for a tool usable on Windows or Linux (x86_32 or x86_64) and preferably [FLOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_terms_for_free_software#FLOSS).

#### Rationale

Unencrypted data can be compressed much better, especially since the installers contain different versions of the same thing and are therefore bound to have redundancies that can be compressed.